# animation in android

Tags: android

I had an activity (say homeActivity) and when I start a new activity(say nextActivity) from my homeactivity i would like to give it an animation effect like appearing it from the bottom. Is it possible in android?

Answer (score 6):

after call to `startActivity`, make call to `overridePendingTransition` with id's of xml defined animations, one for exiting activity, one for entering. See docs for this method [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,int))

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent the default animation (Slide in from the right) with the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION flag in your intent.

i.e.:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

then in your Activity you simply have to specify your own animation.

Answer (score 1):

```
TopListActivity topList;
Vector<BitmapDrawable> images;
int count = 0;
public AnimationAlphaTimer(TopListActivity _topList)
{
  this.topList = _topList;

  this.images = new Vector<BitmapDrawable>();
  for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
  // LOAD IMAGES HERE
  }

  if (this.images.size() > 0) {
    this.topList.slide_0.setBackgroundDrawable(this.images.get(0));

    if (this.images.size() > 1) {
      this.topList.slide_1.setBackgroundDrawable(this.images.get(1));
    }
  }

  this.count = 1;
}

public void launch()
{
  if (this.images.size() >= 2) {
    (new Timer(false)).schedule(this, 100);
  }
}

@Override
public void run()
{
  this.doit();
  this.cancel();
}

private void doit()
{
  if ((this.count % 2) == 0) {
    AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    animation.setStartOffset(3000);
    animation.setDuration(3000);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    animation.setAnimationListener(this);

    this.topList.slide_1.startAnimation(animation);
  } else {
    AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setStartOffset(3000);
    animation.setDuration(3000);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    animation.setAnimationListener(this);

    this.topList.slide_1.startAnimation(animation);
  }
}

public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
{
  if ((this.count % 2) == 0) {
    this.topList.slide_1.setBackgroundDrawable(
      this.images.get((this.count + 1) % (this.images.size()))
    );
  } else {
    this.topList.slide_0.setBackgroundDrawable(
      this.images.get((this.count + 1) % (this.images.size()))
    );
  }

  this.count++;
  this.doit();
}
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
}
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)  {
}}
```

try this i think it will work.